# Can we still submit data after the grant ends?

Tags: usaidopen

We currently submit data collected from a USAID-funded weather station.  We installed it as part of a grant.  As I understand, we have access to submit to the DDL because we have an active grant.  After the grant is over, can we continue to update the data asset with the weather data?

Comment: please note this is a worldwide open data forum and not specific to any platform or country.

Comment: Did the grant come from USAID? In that case, you should ask your contactperson at USAID.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it may require a bit of in-depth discussion.  As CSK notes, talking about this with the AOR/COR for your award would be helpful, but a conversation with the USAID Data Services Team would also help to clarify your question and suggest a path forward.  We do ask that all USAID funded data be registered in the Development Data Library, but it may not always be the best place to host the datasets themselves (continuous weather data is one data type that may not be best suited to the DDL).  Please contact our team at dataservices@usaid.gov so we may discuss this in more detail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to submit a non-USAID location for ongoing data hosting with a final report that can be included with the final upload of data to the USAID Development Data Library.